# Subsonic 3.0 error running ActiveRecord template with SQLite

Tags: subsonic

I've followed the Using ActiveRecord quick tutorial on the website, substituting SQLite in the settings.ttinclude and in the templates themsevles, and when I run custom tool, I get this error:

Error   1   Compiling transformation: Metadata file 'System.Data.SQLite' could not be found C:\testapp\test.dal\ActiveRecord.tt 1   1

I have a reference to System.Data.SQLite in the assembly, has anyone any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It needs to be in the GAC - it will be put there if you run the installer. The reason for this is ... well that's the way VS/T4 rolls ;)

Comment: Cheers Rob - I'm at work now and the solution is on my laptop at home, I've no doubt that will solve my problem. I'd been on the verge of running the installer as well, before deciding to post this question and going to bed instead.